# strikethrough Doesn't work on Telegram node js

Tags: node.js, telegram

I'm using [`"node-telegram-bot-api": "^0.50.0"`](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api)
And I want to use [strikethrough](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options)

```
bot.sendPhoto(channel, url,{
        caption: '~d~ or ~~NO~~',
        parse_mode: 'Markdown',
    });
```

But the result in the chat is:
~d~ OR ~~NO~~ instead if strikethrough text

Bold and italic work properly

Comment: Quote: "To use this mode, pass `MarkdownV2` in the `parse_mode` field. Use the following syntax in your message"

Comment: @ShioT thanks, my mistake, I will switch to HTML, with MarkdownV2 I have to do a lot of escape